# storing data on iOS device using react native

Tags: ios, react-native

I am new to React Native and trying to create a simple iOS app. The app has a button on clicking which I need to store the timestamp of the click on the device in a file.

I know that React Native has an API called `AsyncStorage` but I am getting errors while using this. I copied the code from some site on the net.

Can someone please guide me to use this API?

This is my entire code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component{
  state = {
    'name': ''



}

  componentDidMount = () => AsyncStorage.getItem('name').then((value) => this.setState({'name': value}))

  setName = (value) => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('name': value);
    this.setState({'name': value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput style = {styles.textInput} autoCapitalize = 'none' 
               onChangeText = {this.setName}/>
        <Text>
          {this.state.name}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
      flex: 1,
      alignItems: 'center',
      marginTop: 50
   },
   textInput: {
      margin: 15,
      height: 35,
      borderWidth: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#7685ed'
   }
});
```

As for the error, when I launch the code on iOS, I am getting a red screen. There is no syntax error that I can see.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the code and error you are getting.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Just an update. Retested the code and no errors now. Once I type in text, the app closes. I am running it in expo on a Simulator

Comment: Wrong syntax `AsyncStorage.setItem('name': value);` should be `AsyncStorage.setItem('name', value);`

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without more detail the exact problem you're facing, but I assume some of the following might help you?

Ah I see you posted some code. You will need a constructor that defines your state as well. Added it in my code below.

Please note I'm not an expert. Forgive any errors

```
import {
  AsyncStorage,
} from 'react-native';

class myComponent extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._loadInitialState().done();
  }

  _someFunction() {
    var myData = 123;
    saveItemLocally('data', myData);
  }

  async _loadInitialState() {
    try {
      // get localy stored data
      var dataStored = await AsyncStorage.getItem('data');
      if (dataStored!==null) {
        this.setState({
          data: dataStored
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      //didn't get locally stored data
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  } // end _loadinitialstate

  render () {
    //your render function
    return (
    );
  }
} // end of your component

async function saveItemLocally(item, value) {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(item, value);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('AsyncStorage error: ' + error.message);
  }
}
```